# How To Set up RapidMiner library in Android Studio

Tags: java, plugins, rapidminer, pmml

I am currently working on an object recognition app. I'm using Android Studio and I have created a Neural Network model on Rapid Miner Studio and saved it as PMML. I want to apply this model on a set of extracted features in Android Studio so that I can obtain a prediction (e.g: is the object a fruit/vegetable/nut?). However, I'm not able to integrate the Rapid Miner library in Android Studio. I've downloaded "rapidminer-extension-template" from https://github.com/rapidminer/rapidminer-extension-template. Is it the correct file that should be downloaded?

I have looked for a working solution for the past 4 days but I can't seem to find one.

Do I have to use the Rapid Miner library to apply the PMML model or is it possible to use something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the pmml-evaluator library and added it to my project. The documentation on GitHub helped me achieve what I was looking for; it was able to read the PMML model and provide a prediction.

Also, even if on RapidMiner's website, they say that the PMML writer's list of compatible classifiers is restricted to the ones mentioned, I was able to save the Neural Net model and use it for prediction in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

the extension template is used to create new extensions for RapidMiner, which can provide new Operators.
So in your case you would need is an interpreter of the PMML model in Android. This [project](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-android) looks promising, but I haven't tested it myself.

Also please note, that the Write PMML Operator of RapidMiner currently does not support Neural Network models. The help text states the supported models are :

- Decision Tree Models
- Rule Models
- Naive Bayes models for nominal attributes
- Linear Regression Models
- Logistic Regression Models
- Centroid based Cluster models like models of k-means and k-medoids

Also feel free to ask further, or re-post, questions in the [RapidMiner community forum](http://community.rapidminer.com), especially if you have questions about extension development you can find qualified help there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've downloaded the "JPMML-Model" jar file and added it as library in Android Studio. It supports Neural Network. However, is it possible to save the PMML (Neural Net) model using another software, other than RapidMiner?